# Spring Rest template weird time out exception

Tags: spring, spring-rest

I am using Spring rest template to generate a REST call to a server.

from the application, it returns

```
I/O error on GET request for "http://XX.XX.XX.XX/v1/api":Connect to XX.XX.XX.XX:80 [/XX.XX.XX.XX] failed: connect timed out"
```

But if I use the browser I get the DATA perfectly.

This is the configuration:

```
   @Bean
   public RestTemplate restTemplate() {

       return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
   }
```

What can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your browser is not using some sort of a proxy? What kind of an IP address is that: your local network or some WAN IP? What OS you run your application/browser on?

Comment: it is WAN IP.  The server runs on centos 6 and my computer is MAC.
It works with CURL too.

Comment: Can you tell us the IP?